# Customize mat select dropdown to allow nested values in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm customizing angular material select/autocomplete to allow nested dropdowns.

Here, I wanted to have one parent dropdown with many childs. If I expand particular parent dropdown, only childs of that dropdown should expand or collapse. Similarly, checkbox event should be selected in the same scenario.

Here, I got *[object object]* when I select the dropdowns.

console log is provided to give the values selected/unselected.

Can someone help on this?

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5mizr-final-zrpdxv)

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>

  <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Select Users" aria-label="Select Users" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="states">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">

    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{states.value ? states.value[0] : ''}}
      <span *ngIf="states.value?.length > 1" class="example-additional-selection">
            (+{{states.value.length - 1}} {{states.value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
          </span>
    </mat-select-trigger>

    <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of stateList">
      <div>
        <mat-checkbox [checked]="group.selected" (change)="toggleParent($event, group)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
          {{group.letter}}
        </mat-checkbox>
        <button mat-button (click)="expandDocumentTypes(group)">
                <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
              </button>
      </div>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let name of group.names" [value]="name" [ngClass]="isExpandCategory[group.letter] ? 'list-show' : 'list-hide'">
        <mat-checkbox [checked]="group.checked" (change)="toggleSelection($event, name, group)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
          {{name}}
        </mat-checkbox>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>

  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>



 
export class SelectCustomTriggerExample {
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  // stateForm: FormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  //   stateGroup: '',
  // });
  // toppings = new FormControl();
  isExpandCategory: boolean[] = [];
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
  stateRecord: any = [];
  states = new FormControl();

  expandDocumentTypes(group: any) {
    console.log("expanding dropdown", group);
    this.isExpandCategory[group.letter] = !this.isExpandCategory[group.letter];
    // expand only selected parent dropdown category with that childs
  }

  toggleSelection(event: any, name: any, group: any) {
    debugger;
    console.log("toggleSelection", name, event.checked, group);
    if (event.checked) {
      console.log("stastateRecordtelist", this.stateRecord);
      this.stateRecord.push(name);
      this.states.setValue(this.stateRecord);
      console.log("toggleselection ", this.states.value);
    } else {
      this.stateRecord = this.stateRecord.filter((x: any) => x !== name);
      console.log("else toggleselection", name, group, this.states.value);
      this.states.setValue(this.states.value.filter((x: any) => x !== name));
      console.log("after filter ", this.states.value);
      //this.states.setValue([]);
    }
  }

  toggleParent(event: any, group: any) {
    debugger;
    group.checked = event.checked;
    console.log("event", event.checked, "group", group, "states value", this.states.value);
    let states = this.states.value;
    states = states ? states : [];
    if (event.checked) {
      states.push(...group.names)
    } else {
      console.log("else", states);
      group.names.forEach((x: string) => {
        if (states.indexOf(x) > -1) {
          states.splice(states.indexOf(x), 1)
        }
      });
    }
    this.states.setValue(states);
    console.log("statesvalue", this.states.value);
    if (!event.checked) {
      this.states.setValue(this.states.value.filter((x: any) => !x.includes(group.names)))
      //this.states.setValue([]);
    }
    console.log("final statesvalue", this.states.value);
  }

  stateList = [{
      "letter": "A",
      "checked": false,
      "names": [{
          "id": 1,
          "type": "Alabama"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "type": "Alaska"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "type": "Arizona"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "type": "Arkansas"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "letter": "C",
      "checked": false,
      "names": [{
          "id": 8,
          "type": "California"
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "type": "Colorado"
        },
        {
          "id": 10,
          "type": "Connecticut"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "letter": "D",
      "checked": false,
      "names": [{
          "id": 18,
          "type": "Delaware"
        },
        {
          "id": 19,
          "type": "Denwer"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
}
```

Expected output should look like below

[image]

Comment: Only one group can be selected at one time?

Comment: no, we should mix and match between dropdowns values. on selecting parent dropdown checkbox, all childs should be selected. upon clicking every checkbox, result should be in array with the values selected

Comment: you can refer this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5mizr-n7gmx5.. and see console logs.. here json response changed..

Comment: can anyone tell me how to the auto filter here @UI_Dev

Comment: you need to add autocomplete and specify it in matinput like this [matAutocomplete]="auto"

Comment: @UI_Dev can you include it in your stackblitz. I needs to filter by parent name/child name. If we expand one parent, the other parents should not be expanded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `toggleParent` function with below given. You can also find solution in the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5mizr-final-pxdgby

```
toggleParent(event: any, group: any) {
  debugger;
  group.checked = event.checked;
  console.log("event", event.checked, "group", group, "states value", this.states.value);
  let states = this.states.value;
  states = states ? states : [];
  if (event.checked) {
    states.push(...group.names.filter((x: any) => !states.includes(x.type)).map((x: any) => x.type))
  } else {
    console.log("else", states);
    group.names.forEach((x: any) => {
      if (states.indexOf(x.type) > -1) {
        states.splice(states.indexOf(x.type), 1)
      }
    });
  }
  this.states.setValue(states);
  console.log("statesvalue", this.states.value);
  if (!event.checked) {
    this.states.setValue(this.states.value.filter((x: any) => !x.includes(group.names)))
    //this.states.setValue([]);
  }
  console.log("final statesvalue", this.states.value);
  this.stateRecord = this.states.value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, here there are some bugs..when unselecting and selecting between parent and child checkboxes. can you please help?

Comment: can you please give me test case where you find bug?

Comment: one of the case is .. select Alaska checkbox and then select A parent checkbox.. there are duplicates

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: it works now! Thanks bro. And one more thing, can we able to display Delaware (+3 others) like this in input box? right now its in the below.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: can you please suggest how to do the auto filter here?? @Vivek jain